Translation of ~分だけ
It's about a sentence I read earlier in a book.
俺が助けられた分だけのお返しを。
I do understand the verb "助けられた", which means to be saved.
The part I don't understand is the later phrase "分だけのお返し" as well as the "を" particle in the end.
Thanks in advance.

を is the particle that marks the object of a verb (in this case, お返し). In your sentence, を refers to a verb that is in the context, and parsing it depends entirely on it; you'll have to either add more information (about the context) to the question or parse it by yourself.
For instance, if this is the reply to the question: 明日、何を持ってきますか？, where the verb is 持ってくる, then that would be the verb を refers to.
分 is "the amount", and in your sentence it refers to "how much I have been helped". Here are some examples of 分 with the same meaning:

四ヶ月分の家賃 - four months' rent
あまった分は返して下さい - please return what's left over

だけ usually means "only", but in this context it uses its more uncommon meaning: "enough to".
お返し is what is gifted or given back, e.g. as a way to thank for a favor. It can also mean "revenge" (which is not the case here). Jisho has a good example for this word:

お返しに微積分のノートを貸してあげるわ。 - I'll pay you back with my calculus notes.

You should now be able to put these words together; however, I still don't know which verb を may be referring to, so you'll have to find that first to get a complete translation. The best translation I can suggest without that bit of info would be as follows:

俺が助けられた分だけのお返しを - This is the return gift for all I've been helped with.

Please note that the context may substantially change this sentence's meaning, and this might not be an adequate translation for your book.

The implied verb would simply be something like したい or させてください.

Thanks for the answer. Here is the context
"あの手の感触を、今も覚えている。繋がれた温もりと、暗闇の中で導いてくれた人の優しさを。
だから、恩返しをしたいと漠然と思った。"
This is the prologue so I think it's mostly talking about the past.
I roughly translated as: " I still remember the warmth of that hand. Those gentle hands guided me through the darkness of this world. So, I vaguely want to return the favor. (I don't really understand the "恩返しをしたいと漠然と思った" though) "
And this is the full sentence as well: 暗闇の世界の中で、俺が助けられた分だけのお返しを。

@X2uusud The verb is したい as commented by @ naruto
